# @AutoWired MongoTemplate with multiple profiles

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'd like to know how do I "AutoWire" `MongoTemplate` according to the current active profile.

Basically, I'd like to have multiple profiles (dev, test and prod) and to use `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` in dev, whereas in the test and prod I'd like to connect to a real mongo server.

How do I do that?

P.S
I hope this question isn't too broad and follows the guidelines of SO

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have many profiles you must have different *application.properties* files (eg application-dev.properties, application-test.properties ecc). In order to inject different configuration to MongoTemplate bean you must define in each file the correct Mongo Configuration

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/DATABASENAME
```

When the selected profile is loaded (using `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` parameter https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) Springboot inject the configuration in the environment.